# How can I beat the second boss fight?

Tags: shank

I know I'm playing this game a *little* late, but I can't beat **Gears & Grenades** (Second Boss Fight).
Any *tips*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the grenades and missiles being launched at you, and throw grenades back at the jeep. Use the pickups from the slain bomb soldiers to replenish your grenade stock. My link also tells you how to beat the other bosses if you got any questions about them.

My source is [Gamespy Shank Guide](http://xbox360.gamespy.com/xbox-360/shank/guide/page_3.html)